# Pyglossary, unable to display dictionary in "All" Pages when multiple dictionary selected. macOS Dictionary

Tags: macos, dictionary

Recently, I have using pyglossary to convert CSV and database files into macOS Dictionary apps. It's usable and works fine until I search in "All" Pages in Apps and multiple dictionaries are selected. The Result page isn't displaying any content, only words in the sidebar can display the result of the search. Need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. I have changed the .plist file:

- From `CFBundleDevelopmentRegion` into `Dictionary Languages`
- From "." entries into `CFBundleIdentifier`, `DCSDictionaryManufacturerName`, and `DCSDictionaryCopyright` to have words.

I have also deleted the `DCSDictionaryXSL`, `DCSDictionaryPrefsHTML` and `DCSDictionaryDefaultPrefs`.